How stop Windows 10 firewall warnings when GPO enabled?
This might be better on ServerFault, but trying here first because I think this is the right place.
I have a small network managed by Active Directory and GPO running from a Server 2016. Clients are Windows 10 and 11 mixed. Recently I set up a GPO to enable certain firewall rules that were getting blocked automatically on the default settings. Every since every machine at every log in gives a firewall warning.
The firewall is ENABLED. This isn't like every other instance I've found searching where someone wants to disable alerts on a disabled firewall. I have the firewall enabled and get an alert to "Check Windows Firewall Status" every log in, on both Windows 10 and 11.
I'm trying to figure out what it is Windows is complaining about to make these messages stop. I do NOT want to disable all firewall messages.
My GPO is here...
GPO-Page1
GPO-Page2
GPO-Page3
Firewall-Nag
Firewall-Page
